# Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript Not Injecting Script

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I cannot get the `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` to work. I have looked through all the possible suggestions on stackoverflow and other sites, yet nothing seems to be working. I do not see the "alert" message. I kept simplifying the code until I ended up with a very simple HTML file and just a line of C# code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form></form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the backend C# call:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "AlertTab", "Alert('here!')", true);
```

The script is simply not being appended to the page (I do not see it in the browser HTML). I have tried surrounding the script with `<script>..</script>` tags but it has not changed anything.

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` is being called from `Page_Load`

Comment: is shown html your markup or the page source from the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),
"AlertTab"," <script>alert('here!')</script>", false);
```